# scala: fill non-existing case class after leftOuterJoin

Tags: scala, rdd

I have a paired RDD "A" of case class in this format

```
case class MyCaseClass(ID: String, date: Date, label: String)
```

like this:

```
"ID1", ("ID1", 2006-06-28, "label1")
"ID2", ("ID2", 1996-05-13, "label2")
...
```

I am trying to leftOuterJoin this RDD with a ID array "B" like this

```
[("ID1", "ID1") ("ID2", "ID2") ...]
```

So I did

```
val C = B.leftOuterJoin(A)
```

then I got some output entries look like this

```
("ID",("ID",Some(MyCaseClass("ID",2006-06-28,"label"))))
```

and some other output entries look like this

```
(ID,(ID,None))
```

I understand that this is due to some IDs are present in B but absent in A. Then I wanted to fill those missing values by doing

```
val D = C.map(x => (x._1, x._2._2.getOrElse(MyCaseClass("xxx",9999-01-01,"-999"))))
```

but scala complained with this error message:

```
<console>:1: error: Decimal integer literals may not have a leading zero. (Octal syntax is obsolete.)
    val D = C.map(x => (x._1, x._2._2.getOrElse(MyCaseClass("xxx",9999-01-01,"-999"))))
                                                                       ^
```

I originally asked here ([scala: how to rectify "option" type after leftOuterJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124121/scala-how-to-rectify-option-type-after-leftouterjoin)) a simple version of this same question,
but it seems to be more complicated than I thought.
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying create case class object with date field with Date type, but giving to him literal contains number. You need to create **date** object instead of `9999-01-01`.

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val D = C.map(x => (x._1, x._2._2.getOrElse(MyCaseClass("xxx",format.parse("9999-01-01"),"-999"))))
```

Comment: Thanks! It turned out that I have to use "import java.sql.Date"